# How do I know if my system is frozen?

Tags: freeze

I know Linux rarely freezes, but how can I know if it has?

**It was not frozen, just not responsive, and started responding again after a while, it was chrome using too much memory. The question remains though.**
<del>I have 8gb of ram, of which two are allocated to qemu, installing kali linux. The freeze happened when it was writing the system down to disk. I also had chrome opened with a BUNCH of tabs. Not even the clock is ticking. Also, since I have an HDD I was using cfq as the disk I/O manager. And I use amd's proprietary driver.</del>

In those cases (actually frozen system), should I wait for my system to resume, or use one of the methods described in this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes/), that one of the answers here provided?

Answer (score 1):

freezing means you cant do anything in the desktop even a mouse pointer movement.
[this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes) may help you in such cases.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it partially answers the question, but not quite, since my system had stopped responding completely (worst case scenario in the answer provided), but just waiting was enough to let it normalize again. My doubt is if we can I know if it will resolve itself, or if we need to do any of the provided methods in that answer.

Comment: if your system normalize the problem after some time, i think there is no need to take a action.if you are in a hurry you can try one of those.